# Laravel Eloquent OR query

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have Model with `'scaned_at'` column that I'd like to query like:

```
$properties = Property::where(function($query) {
        $query->where('scaned_at', null)->orWhere('scaned_at', '<', Carbon::now());
    });
```

but it doesn't work and I have no idea why...

Comment: what is the error or output you are getting

Comment: I die and dump $properties and get nothing while I have 2 records in my DB with 'scaned_at' = to null

Comment: $query->whereNull('scaned_at') or Use DB::raw('null');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add `->get();` at the end like:

```
$properties = Property::where(function($query) {
    $query->where('scaned_at', null)->orWhere('scaned_at', '<', Carbon::now());
})->get();
```

Also, you can do it without function inside:

```
    $properties = Property::where('scaned_at', null)->orWhere('scaned_at', '<', Carbon::now())->get();
```